# problem getting xpath function ends-with() to work while contains() works fine

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

i am trying to get the tags that have an attribute that end with a certain id.
like `<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Country">`
i want to get the spans that have the id ends with 'Country'
i try the following xpath `//span[ends-with(@id,'Country')]` but i get the following exception
"Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function."

the strange thing is that contains works fine
so the following xpath works `//span[contains(@id,'Country')]`
any ideas why this happens?
thanks

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a one-liner XPath 1.0 solution that implements the XPath 2.0 e`nds-with()` function. :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**The function** [**`ends-with()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-ends-with) **is not defined for [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath)** **but only for [XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) and [XQuery](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/).**

You are using .NET. .**NET at this date does not implement** [**XPath 2.0**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/), [**XSLT 2.0**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/) or [**XQuery**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/).

One can easily construct an XPath 1.0 expression, the evaluation of which produces the same result as the function **`ends-with()`**:

**`$str2 = substring($str1, string-length($str1)- string-length($str2) +1)`**

produces the same boolean result (`true()` or `false()`) as:

**`ends-with($str1, $str2)`**

In your concrete case you just need to substitute the right expressions for **`$str1`** and **`$str2`**. They are, accordingly, **`/myXml/data`** and **`'World'`**.

**So, the XPath 1.0 expression to use, that is equivalent to the XPath 2.0 expression `ends-with(/myXml/data, 'World')` is**:

```
'World' = 
   substring(/myXml/data,
             string-length(/myXml/data) - string-length('World') +1
             )
```

Answer (score 8):

contains() and starts-with() are in XSLT1; ends-with() is in XSLT2 only.

Comment: You'd have to take that up with the developer.  Which transformer implementation is this?

Comment: Also, notice that `fn:contains` wont give you the same results. You could use: `span[substring(@id,string-length(@id)-6)='Country']`

Answer (score 2):

Date: Jan 6th 2016

For any one reading this answer, these are the Xpath String functions supported in latest .Net 4.6 framework:

**concat**: Returns the concatenation of the arguments.

**contains**: Returns true if the first argument string contains the second argument string; otherwise returns false.

**normalize-space**: Returns the argument string with the white space stripped.

**starts-with**: Returns true if the first argument string starts with the second argument string; otherwise returns false.

**string**: Converts an object to a string.

**string-length**: Returns the number of characters in the string.

**substring**: Returns the substring of the first argument starting at the position specified in the second argument and the length specified in the third argument.

**substring-after**: Returns the substring of the first argument string that follows the first occurrence of the second argument string in the first argument string.

**substring-before**: Returns the substring of the first argument string that precedes the first occurrence of the second argument string in the first argument string.

**translate**: Returns the first argument string with occurrences of characters in the second argument string replaced by the character at the corresponding position in the third argument string.

[MSDN Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256180(v=vs.110).aspx)