# Querying Same Named Elements with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I wrote a Xpath query to look for an element with a nodeValue that contains a string.

```
/campaigns/campaign[contains("7218322441485795", creative_id)]
```

However, the XML I'm querying has multiple `<creative_id>` elements;

```
<campaigns>
    <campaign>
        <creative_id>41485795</creative_id>
        <creative_id>41485759</creative_id>
        <creative_id>41485694</creative_id>
        <resources>
        ....
```

The problem is that the query only evaluates the first `creative_id` element and not second & third.

How do I write the XPath query to not be limited to the first `creative_id` element?

Comment: How do you call this XPath query?

Comment: @Chris http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath

Comment: Do you intend for the arguments to `contains` to be ordered this way? You're currently looking for the value of `creative_id` in that string, not the value of that string in `creative_id`.

Comment: @lwburk - Yes, the query string that I'm comparing is actually 16 digits long. It's only the last 8 I care to evaluate.

Comment: You might have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3470779/592746

Comment: @lwburk Thanks for that, but I'm using DOMXPath of PHP and it only supports XPath 1.0. Not by choice unfortunately. Baked into the framework.

Comment: Yeah, if you look at Dimitre's answer, he shows how to do an `ends-with` in XPath 1.0. You may not need it, but, then again, you might, if you're concerned about strict matching.

Comment: @mellamokb L.O.L. I meant, what code is he using, but of course it is not really applicable as per lwburk's answer.

Comment: @Chris - I knew what you meant :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPath `contains` function returns `true` when the string value of the second argument is found in the first argument. Your ordering seems suspicious. You're currently looking for the string value of `creative_id` in the given string, not the value of that string in `creative_id`.

Assuming that the argument ordering is correct, the following expression returns a `campaign` element if any of its `creative_id` children match a portion of the provided string:

```
/campaigns/campaign[creative_id[contains("7218322441485795", .)]]
```

Comment: Excellent! I don't know how many times I came close to that same solution. Thank you.