# Using an XPath expression within SelectNodes

Tags: c#, .net, xpath-1.0

[I've seen this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469275/problem-getting-xpath-function-ends-with-to-work-while-contains-works-fine) where Dimitre Novatchev shows a way of replicating `ends-with` with an XPath 1.0 expression.  However I am having trouble implementing it in context of within a `SelectNodes` call.

Previously I was using

```
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", root.NamespaceURI);    
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//x:*[contains(name(.), '-notification')]", nsmgr);
```

Which returned all the nodes I wanted plus one I didn't which had an additional 's' on the end (`has-more-notifications`).

So I tried using Dimitre expression which gave me:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//x:*[substring(name(.), string-length(name(.)) - string-length('-notification') +1)]", nsmgr);
```

Which fails miserably giving me the root node of `notification-data-response`.

This is my first foray into XPath and it seems to be like regex - you either understand it or you don't.

How do I implement the expression so it returns only the nodes that end with `-notification`?

**UPDATE**

A sample of the input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notification-data-response xmlns="http://checkout.google.com/schema/2" serial-number="16ceae10-a9f1-4ff0-a77b-c3407f2d684a">
    <notifications>
        <new-order-notification serial-number="653417067275702-00001-7">
        </new-order-notification>
        <order-state-change-notification serial-number="653417067275702-00005-1">
        </order-state-change-notification>
        <risk-information-notification serial-number="653417067275702-00005-5">
        </risk-information-notification>
        <authorization-amount-notification serial-number="653417067275702-00005-6">
        </authorization-amount-notification>
    </notifications>
    <continue-token>CP6u9NeQJxC2y72h-MiUARgG</continue-token>
    <has-more-notifications>false</has-more-notifications>
</notification-data-response>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use local-name() function if you want to avoid namespace prefixes. Something like this should give you all nodes ending with -notification

> //node()[substring(local-name(), string-length(local-name()) -
>   string-length('-notification')+ 1, string-length(local-name()))=
>   '-notification']

Ok .. I tested this here . you can verify too .. XPath is an open standard so all tools should be able to give similar response.

http://www.xpathtester.com/test

INPUT

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<notification-data-response xmlns:x="test">
    <TPI_ADDRESSES>
        <ISPRIMARY>Y</ISPRIMARY>
        <data1>
            <x:wewe-notification/>
        </data1>
        <data2>
            <x:wewe-notification/>
        </data2>
    </TPI_ADDRESSES>
</notification-data-response>
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root>
  <x:wewe-notification xmlns:x="test"/>
  <x:wewe-notification xmlns:x="test"/>
</root>
```

ignore the root node as it is generated to present a valid formatable response.

Now let me break down and explain the xpath to you:

> "//" -- denotes that you are searching doing a wild search or we call full scan.. like you don't
>   care at what level target node comes.
>
> "node()" -- is a reference to any and every node or the current node ....

so now :
"//node()" -- together denote that you are going to evaluate all the nodes in the xml.

**What do you evaluate ?**

**the name** -- you want to find if the name of the node contains "-notification" in it. For that you use the substring function in LHS

> substring(local-name(), string-length(local-name()) -
>   string-length('-notification')+ 1, string-length(local-name()))
>
> RHS is you search string = '-notification'

local-name() = gives the name of the node that you are evaluating at any point excluding prefix
string-length() - length of the node name

Comment: This too returns 0 elements. I've added a sample of the XML.

Comment: Strange .. I ran your input with my xpath and I got the following result`<root xmlns="http://checkout.google.com/schema/2">
  <new-order-notification serial-number="653417067275702-00001-7"></new-order-notification>
  <order-state-change-notification serial-number="653417067275702-00005-1"></order-state-change-notification>
  <risk-information-notification serial-number="653417067275702-00005-5"></risk-information-notification>
  <authorization-amount-notification serial-number="653417067275702-00005-6"></authorization-amount-notification>
</root>`

Comment: I see that on XPathTester with the full XML too.  However in .NET I get 0 elements.  Something seems to be not right with the .NET 3.5 implementation.

Comment: Actually something was not right with my implementation - I had a week set on my timespan for polling and at somepoint on Friday afternoon it had expired and I didn't notice.  However I did need that expression and the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Dimitre's workaround works nicely. You just need to compare the substringed 'ending' with the string constant that you are looking for, i.e.:

```
SelectNodes("//x:*['-notification'=substring(name(.), string-length(name(.)) 
           - string-length('-notification') +1)]")
```

Out of interest, if you can avoid the `//` wildcard by being more specific with the path, you'll improve the performance of your query significantly on a large document.

**Edit**

Here's how I tested this (in MS Visual Studio's xslt parser, which is 1.0):

```
<root>
    <nodeendsin-notification></nodeendsin-notification>
    <alsonodeendsin-notification></alsonodeendsin-notification>
    <nopethisis-notifications></nopethisis-notifications>
    <idontcontainatall></idontcontainatall>
</root>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*['-notification'=substring(name(.), string-length(name(.)) - string-length('-notification') +1)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Returns just the nodes ending in 'notification'

```
<root>
    <nodeendsin-notification></nodeendsin-notification>
    <alsonodeendsin-notification></alsonodeendsin-notification>
</root>
```

Comment: Using that expression gives 0 nodes back. Like I said this is my first use of XPath and hardly anything about it makes sense.

Comment: I've updated. Does your namespace manager include a definition for namespace prefix x?

Comment: @graham.reeds I would suggest you give Vamsi's suggestion a go. Remove the x: prefix and then replace name() with local-name(). This will search nodes in a namespace agnostic manner. Also, if you can post or link your full xml input, we can test with that.

Comment: The full xml input I am testing against is 12K in size.  I will look at trying Vamsi suggestion but I don't understand what it is doing and dislike using things I don't understand.

Comment: I've added a sample of the XML.