# How to use starts-with() , contains() and ends-with() in XPath to find the xml node innertext? in XPATH 1.0

Tags: xslt, xpath, xpath-1.0

```
<ArticleBackmatter>
   <Heading>Ethical standards and patient consent</Heading>
   <Heading>Ethical standards and patient</Heading>
   <Heading>standards and patient consent</Heading>
</ArticleBackmatter>
```

I want to get the inner text with start from "Ethical" , contains "and " and end with "consent" in the Heading node.

Comment: What version of XPath (or what tool/library/language if you don't know the version for sure)?  `starts-with` is available in XPath 1.0 but `ends-with` was only introduced by XPath 2.0 (you have to fake it with `substring` and `string-length` in 1.0).

Comment: I use XPath 1.0 only

Comment: Your question is not clear: what is the expected result of your example?

Comment: Do you only want `Ethical standards and patient consent` if that is the entirety of the content of a text node? Or do you want that string even if there is other text before/after it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One possible way:

```
//Heading[starts-with(., 'Ethical') and ends-with(., 'consent')]
```

The `ends-with()` function is XPath 2.0. In XPath 1.0, [it can be replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3470779/2998271) using `substring()` and `string-length()`. Here is the equivalent XPath 1.0 (wrapped for readability):

```
//Heading[
            starts-with(., 'Ethical') 
                and 
            'consent' = substring(., string-length(.) - string-length('consent') +1)
         ]
```