# Selenium Python Xpath where to insert ends-with to find a text at the end of the string

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have the following Xpath:

```
'.//*[@id="reporting_usn_browser_tab_source_tree_5_crm_f1/5_address"]'
```

I would like to use ends with as I would like to find the text address which is at the end of the string

I have tried:

```
'.//*[@id="reporting_usn_browser_tab_source_tree_5_crm_f1/5_address"][ends-with(@id, 'address']
```

The HTML is:

```
<div>
    <span id="reporting_usn_browser_tab_source_tree_5_crm_f1/3_address" class="" title="" style="">address</span>
</div>
```

My function checks if the address element is not on the page.  The element is not on the page so I would like to return True.

```
def is_address_data_object_element_value_not_displayed_from_expanded_tree(self ): # Check if the address data object value is not displayed. For dataset ID f1/3 the address data object value should not be displayed.
    #data_objet_address_element = self.get_element(By.XPATH, './/*[ends-with(@id, "address")]')
    data_object_address_element = self.get_element(By.XPATH, '.// *[substring( @ id, string - length( @ id) - string - length("address") + 1) = "address"]')
    if data_object_address_element.text is None or data_object_address_element == "":
        return True
```

I get the error:

```
 Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//*[ends-with(@id, "address")] because of the following error: TypeError: Unable to get property 'I' of undefined or null reference
```

I have also tried:

```
data_object_address_element = self.get_element(By.ID, '.// *[substring( @ id, string - length( @ id) - string - length("address") + 1) = "address"]')
```

I get the error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with id == .// *[substring( @ id, string - length( @ id) - string - length("address") + 1) = "address"]
```

What is the Xpath syntax to use ends-with please?

Thanks, Riaz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use starts-with() , contains() and ends-with() in XPath to find the xml node innertext? in XPATH 1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217002/how-to-use-starts-with-contains-and-ends-with-in-xpath-to-find-the-xml-n)

Answer (score 0):

try the below xpath ,

```
.//*[substring(@id, string-length(@id) - string-length('address') +1) = 'address']
```

Comment: I get the error: InvalidSelectorException: Message: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//*[ends-with(@id, "address")] because of the following error:
TypeError: Unable to get property 'I' of undefined or null reference

Comment: The ends-with function is part of xpath 2.0 but browsers  generally only support 1.0. So updated my answer.

Comment: I still get the same error. Ah in the Firefox browser Xpath checker it locates it but in my Python code the error will show

Comment: its working perfectly for me. can you post the code?

Comment: I think I know why, I am asserting if the address element is on the page or not.  The address element is not on the page.  I want to return true if the element is not there.  I have added my method above in my question.

Comment: Well in Xpath checker in Firefox browser it works.  In my Python Selenium code it is not working.  My Function call is above in my question.