# using wildcard to select multiple element

Tags: html, selenium

I have couple of input in html. How can I write an xpath query with a wildcard character to replace the numeric value in the name attribute to select all input elements? I tried `//div/input[contains(@name, "name")]`, it works, but I prefer to use a wildcard. Something like `//div/input[@name="models[.*.].name"]`.

The html:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="models[1].name" value="">
    <input type="text" name="models[2].name" value="">
    <input type="text" name="models[3].name" value="">
    <input type="text" name="models[4].name" value="">
    <input type="text" name="models[5].name" value="">
    <input type="text" name="models[6].name" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: What you actually want ?

Comment: Can you share your code trials?

Comment: You can use a combination of starts-with and ends-with -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217002/how-to-use-starts-with-contains-and-ends-with-in-xpath-to-find-the-xml-n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CssSelector

```
input[name^='models'][name$='.name']
```

This will get you all inputs that have a name which starts with models and ends with .name

There is also a way to do this in XPath, by using

```
//input[starts-with(@name, 'models') and ends-with(@name, '.name')]
```

But this is only supported by browsers using XPath 2.0, so this will **not** work in Chrome

The alternative is to use a Xpath 1.0 compatible way, which isn't really readable

```
//input[starts-with(@name, 'models') and substring(@name, string-length(@name) - string-length('name') +1) = 'name']
```