# PMD custom junit method naming rule not working

Tags: java, pmd

I have the following rule defined in my ruleSet.xml file:

```
<rule ref="category/java/codestyle.xml/MethodNamingConventions">
    <properties>
        <property name="junit4TestPattern" value="[a-z]*_[A-Z]{1}[a-z,A-Z]*_[A-Z]{1}[a-z,A-Z]*"/>
        <property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="//ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration['.*FoobarRepository']"/>
    </properties>
</rule>
```

But when running PMD nothing fails yet I have alot of methods that are not conform the junit4 method naming pattern. All method are annotated with org.junit.Test 
What is needed to trigger junit specific rules ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a bug, your violationSuppressXPath just returns true all the time. Remember, that it's evaluated with the violating node as the context node of the expression.

```rb
//ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration
```

`//` at the start of an XPath expression select all the descendants *of the document root*, so all the nodes in the file. So `//ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration` selects all the nodes of that type in the file, and not necessarily one that encloses the violation node.

```rb
['.*PrincipalRepository']
```

This predicate is always true, because any non-empty string is truthy. A predicate like `['foo']` is evaluated by converting the string to a boolean with the `boolean` function, which yields `true()` if the string is non-empty. (Here you mean to test the name of the class, in the attribute `@Image`)

So basically the predicate doesn't test anything. The effect, is that your `violationSuppressXPath` suppresses the violation any time the file where the violation is found contains *some* ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration anywhere, which is pretty frequent.

To make this work, you could replace it with

```rb
./ancestor::ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration[@Image = 'PrincipalRepository']
```

Note that unfortunately, XPath 1.0 does not support regular expressions so you can't do a regex test (though you can use `contains` or imitate an `ends-with` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26217115/6245827)). In this instance, I think a `@SuppressWarnings("PMD.MethodNamingConventions")` like you came up with is more appropriate.

Comment: PMD provides for XPath 1.0 a own `matches` function to support regex: `./ancestor::ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration[matches(@Image, '^.*PrincipalRepository$')]`

Comment: This is really strange because this does not work for me but `<property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="//ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration['.*FoobarRepository']"/>` works like a charm and it definitely filters classes. I use it for `TooManyStaticImports`

Comment: @Saljack Both rules don't report on the same nodes. TooManyStaticImports reports on the root node, while MethodNamingConventions reports on the method node. The latter has a ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration ancestor but the former doesn't. I'm surprised your expression doesn't filter out all classes. Did you check whether legit violations are still reported?

Comment: Yes I checked it. I have two classes `SomethingFoobarRepository` and `SomethingServiceImpl`. `SomethinFoobarrepository` is filtered but `SomethingServiceImpl` is still there.