# Suppress PMD violation in certain classes

Tags: java, static-analysis, pmd, suppress-warnings, static-code-analysis

I've got `ViewState` POJO classes which have constructors with many parameters. Problem is that PMD is throwing `ExcessiveParameterList` violation on them.

Now I'm trying to suppress this violation for all classes which end with `ViewState.java` (e.g. in `DashboardViewState.java`). I've added
this to my `rules-pmd.xml`:

```
<rule ref="category/java/design.xml/ExcessiveParameterList">
    <properties>
        <!--Ignore ExcessiveParameterList on ViewState classes -->
        <property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="//ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration['*ViewState.java']"/>
    </properties>
</rule>
```

Problem is that this will suppress all violations against `ExcessiveParameterList` no matter in which class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_making_rulesets.html#filtering-the-processed-files - use `<exclude-pattern>` instead of `<properties>`

Comment: But this is just to completely exclude classes from all rules, or not? I just want to suppress one rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56002416/6245827), though since nobody upvoted my answer I can't flag this as a duplicate.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56460327/6245827 for details about why your expression suppresses all violations of the rule.

The solution here is to test the `@Image` attribute of the ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration, and *not* using `//`, but rather an `ancestor` check:

```
./ancestor::ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration[contains(@Image, 'ViewState')]
```

XPath 1.0 doesn't support regex, so you're limited to doing a `contains` check like here, or mimicking an `ends-with` function with `substring`, like explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26217115/6245827)

Comment: Seems to be the same problem, but this question is way easier to understand and to find for others. I've looked around quite a bit to find an answer before creating the question

Comment: @Marius you may be right, this question has a better title

Comment: PMD provides for XPath 1.0 a `matches` function to support regex. You can write the example this way:

`./ancestor::ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration[matches(@Image, '^.*ViewState$')]`